# Xamarin.iOS - Soap Web Service Issues

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, soap, xamarin.ios

I am having problems connecting to [this](https://api.hralliance.net/AllPayData.svc) soap web service via a C# Xamarin.iOS app. I first tested it in a Windows form application and got it to work just fine. However trying to switch it over to a Xamarin.iOS app has been a royal pain.

For the Windows form, I simply used `SvcUtil` to create the `output.config` proxy settings and `Service.cs` file (`AllPayData.cs` in this case). Then added the contents of the config file to `App.config` and added the `.cs` file to the project. I can't follow the same procedure with my Xamarin app, mainly because there is no `.config` file to add the proxy to.

Following various Xamarin tutorials and examples, I came across the Silverlight tool `SlSvcUtil`, which created similar files as the other tool but the proxy file was simpler and the `.cs` file was made up all of async based methods. Wasn't too difficult to adjust to the change of the async methods, the tricky part was just trying to understand how the proxy could or should be tied into all of this. many of the tutorials showed creating an `Endpoint` object and using `BasisHttpBinding` to setup the proxy. Unfortunately I ran into this really annoying 415 error.

```
There was an error on processing web request: Status code 415(UnsupportedMediaType): 
Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml;charset=utf-8'
was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'."
```

I tried many different types of bindings including `BasicHttpsBinding` and `WsHttpBinding` along with many different options. I attempted to copy the setup verbatim from both of the `.config` files created by both tools (first one was `WsHttpBinding`, second one was `BasicHttpBinding`), but that still yielded error 415.

To me this error simply means that the requests I am sending to the API are in the wrong content type and are expected in a soap envelope (as expected). However, I have no idea on how to specify the content type within the bindings. :(

I re-added the first `.cs` file created by the first tool again (the one that worked with the Windows form, and attempted to apply the same binding code to it. I came up with an error indicating that MonoTouch does not allow dynamic creations of proxies. Boooo...

I attempted to add it as a web service by right clicking on my solution. It'll add all the mapping just fine, but nothing will be generated in the `reference.cs` file. I tried copying and pasting the existing `.cs` files that I already had into `reference.cs`, but still wound up with the same errors.

What am I missing here?? If all else fails, will I have to resort to manually making the soap api calls with C#? Or will that even work?